# Pandas convert Date Time object type to Date Time

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and Python. I want to convert Date Time Object to Date Time. I am having one column named requestDate which is for object type. Below is the one sample type

Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 PM GMT+2

I am trying to convert above object into DateTime by adding following code, however its showing error unconverted data remains. I have removed GMT+2. Please help me in this.

```
test_df['requestDate'] = test_df['requestDate'].str.rstrip('GMT+2')
test_df['requestDate'] =  pd.to_datetime(test_df['requestDate'], format='%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M %p')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem last space in data, so added [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then changed `%H` to `%I` for match hours in 12hour format:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'requestDate':['Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 PM GMT+2',
                                       'Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 PM GMT+2']})

test_df['requestDate'] = test_df['requestDate'].str.rstrip('GMT+2').str.strip()
test_df['requestDate'] =  pd.to_datetime(test_df['requestDate'], 
                                         format='%a, %d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p')

print (test_df) 
          requestDate
0 2020-02-04 13:38:00
1 2020-02-04 13:38:00
```

Here add space cannot be used, because also `M` is removed:

```
test_df['requestDate'] = test_df['requestDate'].str.rstrip(' GMT+2')

print (test_df) 
                requestDate
0  Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 P
1  Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 P
```

Possible solution with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and escaped `+`, because special regex character:

```
test_df['requestDate'] = test_df['requestDate'].str.replace(' GMT\+2', '')

print (test_df) 
                 requestDate
0  Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 PM
1  Tue, 04-Feb-2020 01:38 PM
```